# White space to the left of the image

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

When I use the default settings for [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas), a white space is clearly visible and it also pushing the image to the left.

[image]
<sub>(source: [erik-edgren.nu](https://erik-edgren.nu/files/1518912392.jpg))</sub>

Here's the code:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var base_color = '524726';

    $('#geopattern').geopattern(name, { baseColor: '#' + base_color }).text(get_initials(name));

    // ...

    $('body').on('click', '#save', function() {
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#geopattern")).then(function(canvas) {
            $('#hidden-data').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
            document.getElementById("form").submit();
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$hidden_data = $_POST['hidden-data'];
$hidden_name = $_POST['hidden-name'];
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $hidden_data));
file_put_contents('images/avatars/'.$hidden_name.'.jpg', $data);
echo '<img src="images/avatars/'.$hidden_name.'.jpg">';
?>
```

CSS:

```
#geopattern {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    color: #eaeaea;
    cursor: default;
    height: 512px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20em;
    font-weight: 700;
    justify-content: center;
    width: auto;

    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

Is this any bug or is it something I've done wrong? I have the latest release.

Comment: If it's html2canvas, where is your HTML?

Comment: The only thing that html2canvas converts to an image (canvas), is this line: `<div id="geopattern"></div>`

Comment: Empty `<div id="geopattern"></div>`?

Comment: Na. I load the same function on page load. Please see the updated code (sorry about to little code).

Comment: Could you please `console.log($('#geopattern').html())` right before `html2canvas(docum...`?

Comment: It only printing out `EE`.

Comment: Which css is applied to `#geopattern`?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: thank you for the update. I see that `#geopattern` has no explicit `width`.  Is it limited by parent element? If yes, could you please share its css too? (I'm making a snippet)

Comment: The width for `#geopattern` takes the width from body: `body { width: 512px; }`.

Comment: Looks like a found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for sharing the code. Finally it helped to find the bug.

The white gap appears because of `margin: 50px auto;` set on `body`.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xab7h28L/8/). If you uncomment the corresponding line the bug will appear in the result image.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's really weird, because when I tested your possible solution in PHP, it didn't work. Not even your jsFiddle worked for me (locally) :( Here's the complete source code: https://gist.github.com/edgren/abfaceccf05069490851376227df0643

Comment: @Erik, you're welcome! Actually, we could save some time if you posted all that code from the start =))

Comment: Hehe. Yeah. I know :) I didn't think that far. Sorry

Comment: Nice i encounter same problem with bootstrap v4.5 class='container'